What happens when you combine 2 fluorescent compounds, can they fluoresce both colors?

I'm hearing 2 theories of thought here. 1 is the small alkane chain prevents conjugation, making these 2 compounds absorb and fluoresce independently. The other is FRET effects will make it less 50/50, and favor more to the tetracene-side to fluoresce more. Absorbance from the anthracene will go to the tetracene but not vice versa.  But if that were the case, would the colors be altered?

Yes, both may fluoresce separately and some undergo energy transfer, and possibly $\pi -\pi$ interaction which will change the absorption spectrum, but also intramolecular excimer formation if the alkyl chain is a bit longer. What happens will depend exactly on the pair of molecules. CT complex formation i.e. formation of ion pair directly from ground state is unlikely with these molecules and generally the ion pair does not fluoresce. You can calculate the chance of Forster energy transfer guessing/calculating separation and orientation and using experimental emission and absorption spectra.

What about that this whole new compound is not planar, would adding more methyl bridges do?

My fear is that the whole compound may not be fluorescent at all. It will lose the rigidity requirement. Check the classical example of fluorescein and phenolphthalein.

@ACR These compounds would be fluorescent, similar ones have been shown to form excimers when linked. Triphenylmethanes are fluorescent despite being rather floppy , e.g malachite green

@porphyrin a carbon bonded to 4 benzenes cannot do fluorescence, so you're sure a carbon bonded to 3 benzenes can?

Your assumption is not correct,  all the compounds above fluoresce plus many other aromatics, such as pyrene, perylene, benzanthracenes, phenanthrene etc. as do triphenylmethanes, as mentioned above, and tetraphenyl methanes.

@porphyrin I asked a professor who specialized in photochemistry if tetraphenylmethane can do fluorescence and he said no, because they act as a nanorotor.

you can look up tetraphenylmethane fluorescence , you can see a spectrum here https://www.photochemcad.com/databases/common-compounds/aromatic-hydrocarbons/tetraphenylmethane. Just because a molecule is not rigid does not mean that it cannot fluoresce (or phosphoresce), and many rigid molecules do not fluoresce.

@porphyrin I asked ChatGPT if triphenylmethane can do fluorescence and it said by itself no, but they do make fluorescent dyes out of it with add-ons and it fluoresces the malachite green as you said. Maybe you're thinking of triphenylmethane with a singlet sensitizer?
Btw your link shows the emission at 330 nm? That's in UV range.

Well the AI is wrong, you see the experimental spectrum in the link I sent so no matter what anyone/machine thinks about it that is the fact of the matter, it fluoresces.  What is wrong with 330nm? I would expect it to be at that sort of wavelength, a little longer than benzene fluorescence. (In science an experimental fact trumps everything else, no matter what opinions are.)

@porphyrin okay, so it's not fluorescing only in some solution? Cool, I guess I always wanted to know something that can absorb UV-B/C and emit UV-A.

so yes it fluoresces and most probably in all solvents in which it is soluble. The yield will of course differ between solvents. End of.

@porphyrin but if you ignored the specific example in my image, then are there examples where you just add a carbon-alkane bridge between 2 fluorescent compounds, that will cause the 2 compounds to essentially both stop fluorescence?

No, I don't think so if they can each fluoresce on their own. The closest to this happening would be intramolecular excimer formation but this would occur as well as each fluorescing as well to some extent. Forster energy transfer could also occur but this will only change relative yields.
